# Underpromoting a pawn

Tags: rules, pawn-promotion, loopholes

Is it legal to underpromote a pawn to opponent's pieces? For example, in the below position, promoting White's pawn to a Black knight will be a win.

```
[FEN "r7/kPR5/8/K7/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]
[Title "Underpromotion"]
```

Comment: In your above diagram, either if White plays `bxa8` or `b8`, he can substitute the pawn **only** with **white** bishop, white knight, white rook or a white queen. He can not replace the pawn with black piece.

Answer (score 11):

No, it is not.

FIDE Laws of chess, clause 3.7e:

> When a pawn reaches the rank furthest from its starting position it
>   must be exchanged as part of the same move on the same square for a
>   new queen, rook, bishop or knight **of the same colour**.